# Magento 2.1.1 We can't find required columns: sku

Tags: csv, magento, magento2.1

My apologies if a solution has been provided elsewhere. I have searched and could not find anything similar to what I am experiencing. I am trying to upload categories on a Magento CE 2.1.1 website. I have a file with almost 4000 categories and sub categories and the only practical way is to upload via a csv file.

I downloaded a sample file to use and when I upload the same sample file it's working fine when I click Check data" button. However, when I replace the values on the rows with my own and save the file as csv with UTF-8 text encoding, I am getting an error message below. This is also happening when I save the file as csv even without changing the values. I have tested this with a csv file saved from both Mac Numbers and Windows Excel.

I only need to upload Categories (and not products) but I am not sure if this is possible.

File links:

- [Importing](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v0miFqlnh-4IAf4yA5p2MV7FTeVM9Itv)
- [Not importing](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xhz_-5T79dh97CyReC3vjffFP_aywMS_)
- [Actual project sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rm1OUwQhrQthqoDFqDNFoDEES4tGBFIk)

The files are quite similar but strangely one is working and the other is not.

Error

```
We can't find required columns: sku.
Column names: "sku;store_view_code;attribute_set_code;product_type;categories;product_websites;name;description;short_description;weight;product_online;tax_class_name;visibility;price;special_price;special_price_from_date;special_price_to_date;url_key;meta_title;meta_keywords;meta_description;base_image;base_image_label;small_image;small_image_label;thumbnail_image;thumbnail_image_label;swatch_image;swatch_image_label;created_at;updated_at;new_from_date;new_to_date;display_product_options_in;map_price;msrp_price;map_enabled;gift_message_available;custom_design;custom_design_from;custom_design_to;custom_layout_update;page_layout;product_options_container;msrp_display_actual_price_type;country_of_manufacture;additional_attributes;qty;out_of_stock_qty;use_config_min_qty;is_qty_decimal;allow_backorders;use_config_backorders;min_cart_qty;use_config_min_sale_qty;max_cart_qty;use_config_max_sale_qty;is_in_stock;notify_on_stock_below;use_config_notify_stock_qty;manage_stock;use_config_manage_stock;use_config_qty_increments;qty_increments;use_config_enable_qty_inc;enable_qty_increments;is_decimal_divided;website_id;related_skus;related_position;crosssell_skus;crosssell_position;upsell_skus;upsell_position;additional_images;additional_image_labels;hide_from_product_page;bundle_price_type;bundle_sku_type;bundle_price_view;bundle_weight_type;bundle_values;bundle_shipment_type;associated_skus" are invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you opened the file in Excel which will add a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the start of the file. When the Magento importer tries to read the file, it expects the first header/cell to say sku, but it instead sees the BOM.

Two ways to solve this:

1) Don't open it in excel - use Google sheets, or a text editor if you are feeling brave,

2) If you opened the file in excel, close it, open it in notepad++, click encoding up the top and set to "Encode in UTF-8" (NOT "Encode in UTF-8-BOM"). Then save and you are good to go.